# Prove that for every positive integer $n$, $1/3 + 1/9 + \cdots + 1/{3^n} < 1/2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, solution-verification, induction

Base case is $n=1$: $\frac {1}{3} < \frac{1}{2}$. So the base case holds.

Inductive hypothesis for $n = k$: $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac {1}{3^k} < \frac{1}{2}$

Inductive Step for $n = k + 1$:
$$ \left( \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac {1}{3^k} \right) + \frac {1}{3^{k+1}}< \frac{1}{2}.$$

Multiplying the $n = k + 1$ step by $3$:

$$ \left( 1 + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac {1}{3^{k-1}} \right) + \frac {1}{3^{k}}< \frac{3}{2}$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{3} + \cdots + \frac {1}{3^{k-1}} + \frac {1}{3^{k}} < \frac{3}{2} - 1 = \frac {1}{2}.$$

We know this to be true from our inductive hypoethsis. Hence, $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac {1}{3^n} < \frac{1}{2}.$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You are arguing in the wrong direction. You should start from the induction hypothesis and show the step, not the other way round. In this case that is fixable as all your implications go in both directions.

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi do you mind explaining why? It seems everyone else believes it is incorrect...

Comment: You start with writing down the induction step and then you perform operations until you arrive at the induction hypothesis. However, you should proceed the other way round. Otherwise one could argue $0=1$ as we can multiply both sides by $0$ and get $0=0$, which is true.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you very much - I got it now!

Comment: @pinkUnicorn999 Sure. When you assume $ p $ is true and it leads to something which you know that's true, say $ q $, you can conclude that $ p $ is true. Here, you have written th next step and assuming $ n = k + 1 $ is true implies the truthness of step $ n = k $. So, the step $ n = k + 1 $ is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noticed you went in the wrong direction, for the induction step it is better to start from the induction hypothesis, for example as follows

$$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac {1}{3^n} < \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\implies 1+\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac {1}{3^n} <1+ \frac{1}{2}$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \cdots + \frac {1}{3^n} + \frac {1}{3^{n+1}} <  \frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{6}=  \frac{1}{2} $$

which complete the proof.

Comment: Ah thank you - I see my error now!

Comment: Your way is not completely wrong because even if you finish with induction hypothesis the intermediate steps are $\iff$ but in this way I think it is more clear.

Comment: If you could throw some implication arrow in your answer I'd be happy to upvote. I think those arrows were the source of the confusion of the OP.

Comment: @Severin Yes I agree! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider a square of area $1$ and divide it into 3 congruent rectangles.

The area of each rectangle is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Select one of the three rectangles.

Divide one of the remaining two rectangles into three congruent rectangles, select only, as done before. Continue like this.

Irrespective of the number of iterations, the sum never reaches half of the original square.  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Consider, $$S=\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27}+\cdots \tag{1}$$ Now multiply $S$ by 3, $$3S=1+\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27}+\cdots \tag{2}$$ $(2)-(1)$, $$2S=1$$ $$S=\frac12$$
Thus, for finite terms, $$\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{27}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3^n}\lt\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

Also, we can use a formula for the sum of a geometric progression.

It's $$\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{n}}{1-\frac{1}{3}}<\frac{1}{2}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: I'm trying specifically not to use geometric progression and only induction.

Comment: @pinkUnicorn999  Firstly, you did not write it before in your open post. Also, I think it's not so a good way here to use induction.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^i} = \frac{3n-1}{2 \cdot 3^n}$$

So $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{3n-1}{2 \cdot 3^n} = \frac{1}{2}$$

So for finite $k$:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to k} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^i} < \frac{1}{2}$$

or for all finite $n$:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^i} + \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^i}}_{>0} = \frac{1}{2}$$

For $n \to \infty$, we get the equality.

Hence for all finite $n$ the bound holds.

Comment: I'm trying to use only induction and not geometric progression.

Comment: Can't help you then.  I don't see how induction can answer this, even in principle given that the infinite limit is *EQUAL* to 1/2.  Good luck!

Comment: Actually this does not quite work. There could still be finitely many numbers where the bound is false, even if it holds for the limit.

Comment: Your formula is incorrect. It should be $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{3^i} = \frac{1-(\frac{1}{3})^n}{2}$